# SWT.WebKit doesn't load: No More Handles - [Safari must be installed to use a SWT.WEBKIT-style Browser]

Tags: java, browser, webkit, swt

I'm having trouble using SWT.WEBKIT as the Browser for a SWT-Based Java app, and I am now getting this stacktrace upon starting the application on a new machine:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Safari mus
t be installed to use a SWT.WEBKIT-style Browser]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.browser.WebKit.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        [...]
```

Now, I did follow all the steps from the SWT FAQ on how to use Webkit; Safari is installed, the JVM is 32-Bit (just as Safari is, too), and this is running on a Windows XP 64Bit machine. The weird thing is that it works fine on another WindowsXP 64bit machine! Any ideas on how to debug this?

EDIT: It seems that there is a Bug concerning Java 1.7.0u6 and higher supplying their own libxml2.dll which Java tries to load before Webkit's own libxml2.dll. Check out this bugreport for more: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388469

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that Apple moved the "Apple Application Support" folder in the latest Safari installers from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\`

to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\`.

SWT simply cannot find it ([see this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377785)).

There are two workarounds until SWT support of the new folder is added:

- Install [Apple QuickTime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/) or iTunes - they still place "Apple Application Support" in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\`
- Or add `APPLE_INSTALLATION_DIR\Apple Application Support\` to the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was that the Safari installation didn't install the Apple Application Support; after carefully comparing the two machines I found an Installer, copied it over and ran it, and voila, the error is gone.

Anybody know anything about this? Also, could anybody help me out with a (legit) link to this installer, for future reference and updates (no, google didn't help)?