# SWT.WEBKIT is not working in Window-7 (64 bit)

Tags: java, browser, swt

I want to open the webkit browser in SWT using Windows-7(64 Bit) but every time it throws a **"No more handles"** exception. I have the Safari browser & resources installed. How can I solve it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808436/swt-webkit-doesnt-load-no-more-handles-safari-must-be-installed-to-use-a-sw) seems to be related...

Comment: Can you please explain me its related to what.I am not able to understand your comment.

Comment: The question I linked to seems to be the same as yours. The solution seems to be installing "Apple Application Support".

Comment: I installed it & mentioned in environment variable path also.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to Java 7u6 if you're using Java 7. The newest Java 7 release has a dll conflict with the WebKit dlls.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388469

Let me know if that helps!